# Accuracy in rounding

Tags: computer-science, floating-point, rounding-error, computer-arithmetic

**I want to see if the following two rounding statements are true or false. If it is true, I want to prove it, and if it is false, I want to give a counterexample. I assume no overflow occurs in the calculations and the rounding mode used is any one of round down, round up, round towards zero, or round to nearest.**

**$1)$ If $x$ is a nonzero finite floating point number, then $\text{round}(x+x)$ = $2x$.**

**$2)$ If x and y are two finite floating point numbers, then $\text{round}(x-y)$ = $−\text{round}(y-x)$.**

I am struggling to come up with a proper method to solve this. My instinct suggests to me that neither of these statements are true but I am struggling to find a counterexample. And also, if it is true, I am not entirely sure how to proceed with a proof.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance!

Comment: The first is obviously false, consider $x = 0.3$. You get $1$ on the left hand side but $0.6$ on the right.

Comment: And the second is false with "round up" or "round down".  For example $x=0.7,y=0.2$ and "round up": $\text{round up}(0.7-0.2)= \text{round up}(0.5)=1 \not= 0 = - \text{round up}(-0.5)=-\text{round up}(0.2-0.7)$